# My infix and suffix are given, but my prefix is not

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, affix-riddle

My prefix is not known,

Rather it has some meaning or some mark,

But my suffix has magic powers,

And my infix depends on smart remark.

My whole is about choice, has a meaning or two.

Can you guess what I am?

I will add hints as time goes :) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the answer might be

> [Codeswitch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code-switching)

My prefix is not known,
Rather it has some meaning or some mark,

> **Codes** = generally designed so the information is hidden but the meaning can be understood by someone with the right deciphering mechanism.

But my suffix has magic powers,

> **Witch**

And my infix depends on smart remark.

> **Wit**

My whole is about choice, has a meaning or two.

> Codeswitching occurs when a speaker alternates between two or more languages, choosing which words to translate into which languages. I think the author is playing a bit here with "a meaning or two", hinting the switching between languages involved.

Comment: That's correct, great job !

Comment: I didn't even know that was a word :)